# Memory seemingly not released by lower level allocation routines after free

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind, massif

I'm debugging a complex C++ application, tens of thousands of lines, many nested objects (i'm saying this because it might be relevant re memory fragmentation), it is also OMP/MPI parallelised (although running single node here).

The basic loop goes over chunks of the problem, at every chunk it loops over all relevant objects and does something. These objects internally cache intermediate results through mutable members. At the end deCache routine is called where all these intermediate results should be cleared and we go to the next chunk. The problem is that the memory does not seem to be released at this step and the program runs out of memory after a couple of chunks.

I ran valgrind through the debugger and issued a detailed snapshop at the end of the chunk processing, just before decaching and just after decaching. This shows memory consumption on the heap going from 23Gb to 820Mb, just as expected:

```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0 12,019,170,891,847   23,406,329,728   23,015,422,037   390,907,691            0
98.33% (23,015,422,037B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->44.49% (10,414,094,336B) 0x771D63: FTCinvdCdp::FTCinvdCdp(FTCinvdCdp const&) (new_allocator.h:104)
    | ->37.49% (8,774,281,216B) 0x5B6F4E: FTCinvdCdpZ::clone() const (stl_construct.h:75
...
```

dropping too

```
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
          n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)        stacks(B)
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      0 12,020,946,295,906      857,944,344      830,426,901    27,517,443            0
    96.79% (830,426,901B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
    ->21.15% (181,458,432B) 0x712267: void std::vector<GTHSpecSampFunc, std::allocator<GTHSpecSampFunc> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<GTHSpecSampFunc>(GTHSpecSampFunc&&) (new_allocator.h:104)
    ...
```

These numbers are precisely within what I expected. The problem is that the memory as shown under top barely decreases (and indeed it runs out of memory after a while). Running massif with --stacks-as-heap, it does indicate the memory is not actually released:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0 12,286,840,539,442   24,112,730,112   24,112,730,112             0            0
100.00% (24,112,730,112B) (page allocation syscalls) mmap/mremap/brk, --alloc-fns, etc.
->99.54% (24,000,663,552B) 0x84392D9: mmap (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
| ->54.83% (13,220,446,208B) 0x83CB2DF: new_heap (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
| | ->53.44% (12,884,901,888B) 0x83CDB19: _int_malloc (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
| | | ->53.44% (12,884,901,888B) 0x83CE6AF: malloc (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
| | |   ->53.44% (12,884,901,888B) 0x7C74806: operator new(unsigned long) (new_op.cc:49)
| | |     ->28.94% (6,979,321,856B) 0x771D13: FTCinvdCdp::FTCinvdCdp(FTCinvdCdp const&) (new_allocator.h:104)
...
```

barely changing to

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      0 12,292,664,324,363   23,777,185,792   23,777,185,792             0            0
    100.00% (23,777,185,792B) (page allocation syscalls) mmap/mremap/brk, --alloc-fns, etc.
    ->99.53% (23,665,119,232B) 0x84392D9: mmap (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
    | ->54.47% (12,952,010,752B) 0x83CB2DF: new_heap (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
    | | ->53.06% (12,616,466,432B) 0x83CDB19: _int_malloc (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
    | | | ->53.06% (12,616,466,432B) 0x83CE6AF: malloc (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
    | | |   ->53.06% (12,616,466,432B) 0x7C74806: operator new(unsigned long) (new_op.cc:49)
    | | |     ->28.22% (6,710,886,400B) 0x771D13: FTCinvdCdp::FTCinvdCdp(FTCinvdCdp const&) (new_allocator.h:104)
    | | |     | ->24.84% (5,905,580,032B) 0x5B6EFE: FTCinvdCdpZ::clone() const (stl_construct.h:75)
    | 
...
```

I'm pretty sure we deallocate all vectors correctly (with swap by empty vector) and that there are no classical memory leaks (ie very consistent use of auto pointers, etc.) and besides I would expect these to show under vanilla (i.e. not pages-as-heap) run.

Any idea of what might be going on?  What kind of errors do only show in pages-as-heap run? Any chance it might be a memory fragmentation problem? How does one fix that?

Answer (score 2):

This is typical in systems with virtual memory.  The underlying "memory allocation" routine ("brk") is really only increasing the size of your address space.  The virtual memory system provides pages of actual memory as your process needs it, and steals them back for other processes as they need them.  So, there isn't much reason to readjust the end of your memory space as it's pretty much just a number.

Comment: But in "top" not only does virtual memory increase, so does the resident memory and when that numbers becomes too large it crashes. So I don't worry about this for academic reasons, but very real in the sense that I can't get my program to run to completion... :)

Comment: As @JSF suggests, the first thing I would check is: are you running out of swap space?

Comment: I don't think there was really that question:  The problem described implies running out of swap space.  The question seems to be "why".  Is it a strange kind of memory leak, or is it fragmentation, or is it simply requiring more memory than the system has?  My suggestion was to deal with the shortage of swap space by allocating more, either before or instead of figuring out "why".

Answer (score 2):

It is probably easier to solve the problem by adding swap space to the system rather than by fixing the code.

It is very hard to dig any useful information out of the data you posted.  Maybe with better information or better explanation of the information, you could get better help distinguishing between:

1) Your program is actively using more memory than you understand.  With extra swap space it will run much slower, but at least complete.

2) Your program is leaking big memory chunks.  With extra swap space, your program will just slow down a little as the kernel figures out which pages your program isn't still accessing.

3) Your vectors are pathologically fragmenting the virtual address space creating exactly the same conditions as (2) without an actual memory leak bug.

4) Your program is pathologically leaking tiny chunks of memory intermixed with those it still accesses, creating conditions similar to (1).

5) You managed the almost impossible mix of fragmentation by tiny object allocation/release to created the same conditions as (4).

I could wild guess (3) is more likely.  But not by much and acting on 3 specifically would be significant effort compared to just increasing swap space.

Some extra basics you might need to understand.  Only very large individual allocations are supposed to be returned from the process to the OS when deallocated.  If your memory use is a large number of small to moderate allocations, then it is correct for none of it to be returned to the OS, so `top` should never see any release on memory.  But since you release so much memory, it **should** consolidate well within the process and be available for reuse with very little fragmentation during the next peak in the program's active memory use.  So one theory is that all that does happen:  effective consolidation during a valley in memory use, followed by effective reuse of that memory in the next peak.  You see something unexpected in `top` not because of a malfunction but because your expectations are wrong.  Then the program fails due to lack of memory, not because it failed to reuse the memory released from an earlier peak, but because the current peak in memory use is just too big for available memory.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add a static member in your classes.

static unsigned long count_of_objects ;

Increment that value in your constructor. Decrement it in your destructor.

Create function that will print the counter and set it up so that it can be called from the debugger.

That will show if your objects are, in fact, being deleted.

You can start at a root class and work your way down if there are problems.

From your description, I suspect a memory deallocation problem.

The alternative, as others have mentioned is that the virtual address space grows but does not shrink when you allocate more memory. It is possible you are running into virtual memory issues but I think a deallocation problem is more likely.